# WordPress transient after Using WooCommerce.NET

Tags: c#, wordpress, wordpress-rest-api, woocommerce-rest-api

I Connected WooCommerce.NET API wrapper to my WordPress website.
Then it started building transient none stop.
I even restored website full backup to make it stop. but it wont. in 3 hours, it builds almost 3.000 transients.
_transient_wc_child_has_dimensions_15818
and
_transient_timeout_wc_child_has_dimensions_15818
are some of these transients.